# Date formatting in Blazor dotnet 5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

After updating Blazor WASM from dotnet core 3.1 to dotnet 5, I have a problem with date formatting. The problem is visible when running Visual Studio in debug mode (F5), but not visible when not when running without debugging (Ctrl+F5). It is also an issue on iOS and some other devices. In Chrome I see it correctly, however, not in Norwegian as expected.

```
@recordTimeDTO.DateActive.ToString("dddd dd. MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb-NO"))
```

Result:  Mon 24. M05 2021 (Note M05 as a month)

```
 @recordTimeDTO.DateActive.ToString("F", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb-NO"))
```

Result: 2021 M05 24, Mon 09:27:10

Most importantly, how do I format it so I see a month name and secondly, how can I get this in Norwegian?

Comment: Why are you using. `CerateSpecificCulture` instead of `GetCultureInfo` ?

Comment: Thanks! I changed it now but did not solve the issue. It still shows the same output.

Comment: Why are you changing the user's culture *on the client* in the first place? I suspect you're running into the issues [described in the localization section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-webassembly) of the docs. Blazor Wasm will pack only what's needed based on the end user's language preferences. This works for business users who leave their browsers to their default settings. It's typically developers who switch to `en-US` and encounter localization issues. As the docs show, you can als specify a culture (if needed)

Comment: If users really need to frequently change cultures, or display data with mixed cultures in the same pages, you'll probably have to set `BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData` in the project file. If you want users to specify a preferred language through settings you can set it in `Blazor.start` instead of every format operation.

Comment: Setting the culture is a secondary issue. That was in an attempt to solve the issue with the month showing as M05 for May, or M04 for April as it disregarded the string formatting I applied. This @recordTimeDTO.DateActive.ToString("dddd dd. MMM yyyy") displays the month as M05 for May in iOS and some other devices as well as always when running debug from Visual Studio..

Comment: I added this to the project file but did not solve the issue:
<PropertyGroup>
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
</PropertyGroup>

Comment: Looks like a bug, [already reported by others](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30896) and closed by a bot because .... the person that reported the bug was too slow to say they'd used `BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with `recordTimeDTO.DateActive.ToString("F", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK"))` and then it shows correctly, so seems to be a bug as described by Panagiotis Kanavos.

Comment: This worked for me.  Danish is close enough to Norwegian for it to work for months. But it is a bug. no-NB should work, but you get M01, M02, etc. True, Norway was once a part of Denmark, but 1814 is a long time ago.